# É possível disparar um arquivo dentro de um servidor através de uma página web?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, node.js

Gostaria de saber se é possível executar um comando dentro de um servidor através de uma página na Web, o que eu preciso é que através dessa página eu possa abrir um script VBS que tenho salvo ou até mesmo abrir um aplicativo. Não importa a linguagem aplicada, há uma maneira fácil de se fazer isso?

Comment: Acredito q php faz facil isso: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que nesse caso o senhor deva procurar uma dependência se não quiser criar algo muito complicado. Com poucos minutos de pesquisa, encontrei este:

- [`node-command-line`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-command-line).

Não tenho muito conhecimento em C/C++, mas creio que com um *addon* você também possa chegar em resultados parecidos. Leia mais sobre criar *addons* para Node.JS na [documentação oficial](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/n-api.html).